# I am working on AMAZON mobile hub. When i execute my project it shows following error. Kindly help me what could be the possible solution

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-mobile-hub

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.amazonaws.mobilehelper.auth.signin.SignInActivity@label value=(@string/username_text) from AndroidManifest.xml:26:124-161
>       is also present at [AWS21april:AWSMobileHelper:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:26:13-59 value=(@string/title_activity_sign_in).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-173 to override.

Answer (score 1):

Certain resources related to Cognito User Pools were moved from the app module to the AWSMobileHelper module in the sample download for Android from AWS Mobile Hub. If you are using the latest version of the sample app with an existing project,  you should ensure that the resources are not duplicated in both places in your project when copying over the newest version of the AWSMobileHelper module.

If you are running the sample app directly, you should be able to re-generate the sample app from Mobile Hub by downloading the sample app for your project again. Let me know if the problem you are experiencing occurs with the latest downloaded sample app.

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider accepting my answer and upvoting :)

Comment: Hi Jeff, AWS mobile hub newbie here! Do we need to add the AWSMobileHelper module from the sample app to our project to get AWS working? I'm trying implement user sign in(email and password) in my app but there are a lot of references to AWSMobileHelper classes in the sample code. Any help/pointers appreciated